# Count elements in arrays -Java

Tags: java, arrays, count

I would like to count the value of elements in my array.

**Example:**
Elements in the Array

```
a={"AB", "CD", "EF", "CD", "CD", "GH", "EF"}
```

so the counter for `CD` should be 3.

Thats what I tried. I think the main Problem is that I have no Array where the Elements are stored.

```
public int countValue(final String[] strings, final String value) 
    {
        int counter=0;


                for(int i = 0; i<strings.length; i++)
                {
                    if(value==strings[i])
                    {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                return counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: *I have no Array where the Elements are stored.*?. Well, then create one. Also, use `equals()` to compare Strings. I don't know how you are trying to fix this issue (you will have duplicates in your current code)

Comment: `==` goes to `.equals` and you're pretty much there.

Comment: The answer can be found by looking at the "duplicate" I've spotted. Do study it carefully.

Comment: Compare String using `String.equals()` and not `==`

Comment: The "duplicate" is only a part of the solution. the whole solution is the comment of @TheLostMind

Comment: @Jens - It was either a dupe hammer or "too broad" :(. The OP should probably read about `Map`s and `Set`s too

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `.equals()` method to compare two strings. The `==` operator checks whether both are the same object

Comment: ok ..so far but I need two ararys to compare and use the equals method right?

Comment: value.equals(strings[i]) should do the job